# why inherited functions changes the member variables in base class not the one of the same name of object called it

Tags: c++, oop

I want to ask why the setX function here sets the x member variable in class A not the member variable x in class D even though I call setX function through D object?
How does the compiler did that  ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{

public:
    int x;
    A() { cout << "A cons" << endl; }
    void setX(int i){ x = i; cout << "setxA" << endl; }
    void print() { cout << x; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int x =30;
    B() { cout << "B cons" << endl;  }
};



class D : public B {
public:
    D() {
        cout << "D cons" << endl;

    }
    void func() {
        setX(10);
        cout << x << endl;
        cout << B::x << endl;
        cout << A::x << endl;


    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func();
    return 0;
}
```

the output from this code is 
30
30
10

Comment: it is in class B and class D inherits it from class B

Comment: Because `A::setX()` is a member of class `A`, not of `B` or `D`.   Your question is akin to asking why a dog walks using its own legs, rather than using the legs belonging to another dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class B has an x and also A has an X. As this, you have two x in B!
So you may remove the x from your B class?

If you need both, you can access them with

A::x or B::x inside a method of B which you already did.

So your D class have also both x and calling setX calls the setX method of A. As in D you see the x from B which hides your x from A everything works as expected.

Your method A::setX did not know that you derive later from it. If you want to override the method, B has define a own B::setX which will then also be used in D.

Example how to override a method and access the parameter in derived class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int x;    // A::x 
        int y = 40; // A::y

        // this function only knows about A::x
        void setX(int i){ x = i; cout << "setxA" << endl; }
        void setY(int i){ y = i; cout << "setyA" << endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        int x =30; // this x ( B::x) hide A::x
        int y =50; // this y hides also A::y

        // now we override setY from A ( hiding setY from A! )
        void setY(int i){ y = i; cout << "setyB" << endl; }

};



class D : public B {
    public:
        void func() {
            setX(10);   // Calls A::setX, as A::setX only knows about
                        // A::x it will access A::x
            cout << "X" << std::endl;
            cout << x << endl;
            cout << B::x << endl;
            cout << A::x << endl;

            setY(90);
            cout << "Y" << std::endl;
            cout << y << endl;
            cout << B::y << endl;
            cout << A::y << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in D i see x in B, so why setX changes x in A not x in B ? x in D remains 30 and x in A changed to 10

Comment: Ok I got it , do you have any idea about how the compiler did that ? I meant when the compiler decides that the x in the body of setX is the one in A not in B ? at the time I called the setX the whole object was created so the x of D is the one on B

Comment: Again: A::setX did not know anything about B::x. A method of a class always access the attributes of the class it is defined in, or if not defined there, it inherits from. So if you move A::setX to B::setX, B::setX will access B::x if x is also defined in B. If you then remove x from B then B::setX will access A::x

Answer (score 1):

This is called name hiding. Both `A` and `B` have a member `x` and **both** members always exist (you just cannot access them the same way). `A` knows about his member `x` and so the `setX` function sets exactly this member `A::x`. In `B`, you define another `x` which **hides** `A::x`. This means that if you do

```
B obj;
obj.x = 10;
```

or

```
D obj;
obj.x = 10;
```

you will access `B::x` both of the times (because `B` is lower in the inheritance hierarchy and therefore hides `A::x`).

Here is an example of how you can still access `A::x` using different casts.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x = 0;
    void setX(int i) { x = i; }
};

struct B : A {
    int x = 20;
};

int main()
{
    B obj;
    A castToA = static_cast<A>(obj);
    A* castToAPtr = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&obj);

    std::cout 
        << "access via B:        " << obj.x << "\n"
        << "access via A:         " << castToA.x << "\n"
        << "access via A*:        " << castToAPtr->x << "\n"
        << "access via B::(A::x): " << obj.A::x << "\n\n";


    obj.setX(100);
    std::cout << "set x to 100\n\n";

    std::cout 
        << "access via B:        " << obj.x << "\n"
        << "access via A:         " << castToA.x << "\n"
        << "access via A*:        " << castToAPtr->x << "\n"
        << "access via B::(A::x): " << obj.A::x << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

which yields the output:

```
access via B:       20
access via A:       0
access via A*:      0
access via B::A::x: 0

set x to 100

access via B:       20
access via A:       0
access via A*:      100
access via B::A::x: 100
```

Comment: I want setX in A to change the x in B is that possible ?

Comment: @AyatSalman theoretically yes but that would be a terrible solution (seriously, don't do that). Why do you redefine `x` in the first place anyway?

Comment: I redefine it because I'm trying to understand how the inherited functions in the derived classes work and access the members variable

Comment: @AyatSalman well, lesson learned I gues. Never access child members from within a base class (this doesn't apply to c++ only, but rather to every language that supports inheritance).